# How computer knows how much charged battery is?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-engineering

How does phones and laptops knows how much charged the battery is? I found lot's of simple devices like tv remote can also do that. Whats the mechanism behind that and does it vary with different types of battries? (like Li-ion or magnisium in the field of physics not computing ).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the battery voltage depends slightly on how charged the battery is. The device uses a measurement of voltage to determine the charge. There are varying degrees of sophistication on how the voltage is measured and calibrated, which can give you better or worse estimates of the charge.

In a Li-ion battery for example, charging the battery means moving ions towards one electrode. As the electrode becomes filled with ions, it requires more work to add even more ions, which appears as a potential difference, or a voltage.